# Understanding Function Documentation in Spark in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Scala & trying to understand the [Function Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) for Scala in Spark. the 'flatMap' function has documentation like this

```
def
flatMap[U](f: (T) ⇒ TraversableOnce[U])(implicit arg0: ClassTag[U]): RDD[U]
Return a new RDD by first applying a function to all elements of this RDD, and then flattening the results.
```

Although I know what exactly flatMap does, understanding the documentation seems to be too Cryptic(with letter like U, f, T etc...). Would appreciate if someone can explain what exactly each part of this documentation conveys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `def flatMap`: this is a method called flatMap.
- `[U]`: it's generic, with one type parameter, `U`.
- `(f: (T) ⇒ TraversableOnce[U])`: it takes one argument, `f`, of type `T ⇒ TraversableOnce[U]` (`T` is the generic parameter of `RDD` itself, so e.g. if you have an `RDD[String]` then `T = String`). So `f` is a one-parameter function that takes a `T` and returns a `TraversableOnce[U]`. Remember that `U` is the type parameter (generic) on the method. So you can call this method with any function that takes `T` and returns `TraversableOnce[Something]`.
- `(implicit arg0: ClassTag[U])`: the method requires an implicit parameter of type `ClassTag[U]` to be available. Implicits like this often constrain what types a type parameter can be. In this case `ClassTag` means that the type `U` needs to have concrete type information available at compile time. In practice you can ignore this unless you're trying to call `flatMap` from a generic method of your own.
- `: RDD[U]`: the method returns an `RDD[U]`. Remember `U` was the type parameter on the method. So if you call `flatMap` with an `f` that returns `TraversableOnce[Int]`, the return type will be `RDD[Int]`; if you call `flatMap` with an `f` that returns `TraversableOnce[Potato]` the return type will be `RDD[Potato]`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
def flatMap[U](f: (T) ⇒ TraversableOnce[U])(implicit arg0: ClassTag[U]): RDD[U]
```

Try replacing `T` with `Person` and `U` with `Pet`.

`flatMap` takes a function `f` as an argument. This function takes an instance of type `Person` as an argument, and returns a collection of `Pet`s - i.e., that person's pets. `flatMap` will then return a single collection of `Pet`s - i.e., `RDD[Pet]`.

```
def flatMap[Pet](f: (Person) ⇒ TraversableOnce[Pet])(implicit arg0: ClassTag[Pet]): RDD[Pet]

//usage   .
val allPets = people.flatMap(person => person.pets)
```

The implicit `ClassTag` on the second parameter list is a different story. That's used to ask the compiler to create a manifest for the type `Pet`, so that `flatMap` can reflect on the type.

Read more about it here: [TypeTags and Manifests](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html)